# mapview details

Tags: objective-c

Hi all i want to use the mapview sample code to know the current location.Please give me the code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to do something yourself and show your efforts before posting here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, mapview don't give the current location.
You have to use coreLocation (you can see [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has great sample code. Try searching for "LocateMe" in the Xcode documentation, which a sample app using maps and core location. If you have more specific questions, ask them here on Stack Overflow.